# Max/Min Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, radicals, fractions

For $x$, $y$, and $z$ positive real numbers, find $\frac{z}{x}$ such that $(x,y,z)$ achieves the maximum value of $$\sqrt{\frac{3x+4y}{6x+5y+4z}} + \sqrt{\frac{y+2z}{6x+5y+4z}} + \sqrt{\frac{2z+3x}{6x+5y+4z}}.$$ I found that the maximum value was $\sqrt3$ from Cauchy's Inequality, but I don't know how to actually achieve the maximum. I know that the terms must be proportional, but I don't know how to go from there. Any help on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why don't you post your working, then it would be easier to pinpoint how to get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would go about it: As the expression is homogeneous, we can set $6x+5y+4z=1$ WLOG.  Then CS inequality gives:
$$(\overline{3x+4y}+\overline{y+2z}+\overline{2z+3x})(1+1+1)\ge \left(\sqrt{3x+4y}+\sqrt{y+2z}+\sqrt{2z+3x} \right)^2$$

So we get $\sqrt{3x+4y}+\sqrt{y+2z}+\sqrt{2z+3x} \le \sqrt3$ and equality is possible iff 
$\dfrac{3x+4y}1=\dfrac{y+2z}1=\dfrac{2z+3x}1 \implies x:y:z = 1:3:6$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\sqrt{1+1+1}$ instead of $1+1+1$?

Comment: @YuiToCheng It is correct as written.

Answer (score 1):

It's $(a+b+c)^2\leq3(a^2+b^2+c^2)$
The equality occurs for $3x+4y=y+2z=2z+3x$.